# Google Slides: modifying the thumbnail view

Tags: google-slides-api

Is it possible to modify the thumbnail view? Normally in the default view of a presentation, the slides are shown on the right (or middle if 'image options' etc. is selected), and a scrollable list of numbered slide thumbnails is shown on the left. Is it possible to get access to this scrolling list? Specifically, I want to add icons below the number (e.g. 'skip / print / priority', etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So far what I understand in your question is to use **[Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)**. Where you need to customized your presentation as a whole.

> Applies one or more updates to the presentation.
>
> Each **[`request`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#Request)** is validated before being applied. If any request is not
>   valid, then the entire request will fail and nothing will be applied.
>
> Some requests have **[`replies`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/response#Response)** to give you some information about how they
>   are applied. Other requests do not need to return information; these
>   each return an empty reply. The order of replies matches that of the
>   requests.
>
> For example, suppose you call batchUpdate with four updates, and only
>   the third one returns information. The response would have two empty
>   replies: the reply to the third request, and another empty reply, in
>   that order.
>
> Because other users may be editing the presentation, the presentation
>   might not exactly reflect your changes: your changes may be altered
>   with respect to collaborator changes. If there are no collaborators,
>   the presentation should reflect your changes. In any case, the updates
>   in your request are guaranteed to be applied together atomically.

Try also to explore **[REST Resource: presentations.pages](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages)**. You will need the relevant information from here to organized a specific page from your presentation.

Just explore the page and I think you get essential details from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I don't think they answer the question. Updates only apply to the content of slides themselves, not to the app's presentation of them. I can't find any hooks in the api to actually customize the default 2/3 column layout. I guess it's just not available yet.